# How to solve this error - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (YXK.SYS_C0010166) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

How to solve the following error resulting from the code?

This is my error:

```sql
INSERT INTO payment VALUES('P0400',320.50,'PayPal','2020-08-30','S0080','TD400')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (YXK.SYS_C0010166) violated - parent key not found
```

This is the code:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
Column ticket_ID FORMAT A10
SET LINESIZE 600
SET PAGESIZE 200

- --Create Table



    CREATE TABLE payment(
        payment_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        payment_Total NUMBER(10,2),
        payment_Method VARCHAR(20),
        payment_Date DATE,
        staff_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        ticket_detail_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(payment_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(staff_ID) REFERENCES staff(staff_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(ticket_detail_ID) REFERENCES ticket_order_detail(ticket_detail_ID)
    );
```

Comment: Check the value inserted in this table for column staff_ID and ticket_detail_ID because foreign key constraint will enforce that values inserted in this table should be present in parent table i.e. staff and ticket_order_detail

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is a common one, and it basically just means that you tried to create a *child* record in the `payment` table which is referring to a non existent *parent* record in the `ticket_order_detail` table.  Specifically, the record you attempted to insert into `parent` is referring to a `ticket_detail_ID` value of `S0080`, and no such record in `ticket_order_detail` exists.

The remedy here is to make sure that `ticket_order_detail` has such a matching parent record.  One way to do this would be to insert a new record into this table with a `ticket_detail_ID` value of `S0080`.